# How to disable a submit button if no changes were made in an input field?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an issue where I have multiple input fields with user's data from the database and he can edit them. The form is working fine, although, even when nothing is changed, the submit button is enabled. How do I disable it?
Here is the function part of my code:

```
const handleUpdateData = async (ProfileData: any) => {
        const {
            name,
            surname,
            description,
            company,
        } = ProfileData;

        const dataUsername = {
             name,
             surname,
             company,
             description,
        }

        await mutateAsync({
            userId: user?._id,
            dataUsername
        }).then(res => {
            console.log('success')
        })
        await queryClient.refetchQueries('current-user')
    }
```

and one input controller

```
<Controller
   control={control}
   render={({onChange, onBlur, value}) => (
     <TextField
         name='name'
         variant="outlined"
         className={classes.input}
         onChange={onChange}
         onBlur={onBlur}
         value={value}
       />
)}
name="name"
rules={{required: true}}
defaultValue={user.name}
/>
```

and the submit button

```
   <Button onClick={handleSubmit(handleUpdateData)}>
     {'save'}
   </Button>
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Are you using **react-hook-form** here? If so you can check for **isDirty**  property.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how your `handleSubmit` function looks like but this is how i handle it, assuming the ***default** value are from props. I'm using lodash's `isEqual` but you can use other object comparison functions.

```
const Component = (props) => {
      const [ state, setState ] = useState(props);

      const handleChange = (value) => {
           setState({...state, field: value}) //example of state change
      }

      return (
            ..... input form
            <Button disabled={isEqual(props, state)}></Button>
            //using isEqual to compare props and state, if it's different, change happened.
       )



}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have state in the same component with the input value stored in it just like this

```
this.state = {
   inputValue : ''
};
```

you can use this prop `inputValue` to check if it's empty or not like following:

```
<Button {!this.state.inputValue && "disabled"} onClick={handleSubmit(handleUpdateData)}>
    Save
</Button>
```

#### Or With Hooks

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

<Button {!inputValue && "disabled"} onClick={handleSubmit(handleUpdateData)}>
    Save
</Button>
```